# If X and Y are independent random variables and X is independent of f(X,Y), what can be said about f?

Tags: random-variable, independence

I know that if $X$ and $f(X)$ are independent, then $f$ is almost surely constant. Thomas Lumley has pointed out that very little can be said about $f$ without additional constraints: what if the constraint is that $X$ and $Y$ have either (a) continuous distributions, or specifically (b) Gaussian distributions?

Answer (score 1):

Not very much without more restrictions.  As an example, suppose $X$ and $Y$ take the values $-1$ and $1$ with 0.5 probability each, and let $f(X,Y)=XY$. Then $X$ is independent of $f(X,Y)$ and $Y$ is independent of $f(X,Y)$, but $f(X,Y)$ has the same set of values as $X$ or $Y$.

Comment: We can have $f(X,Y) = f(Y)$, thus constant as function of $X$. This mirroring (that f(-1,Y) and f(1,Y) have the same distribution) might be the only other situation.

Comment: I'd be a bit surprised if you couldn't get something similar with a more complicated $f$ and more values for $X$ and $Y$

Comment: I got another one. Let $X\sim U(0,1)$ and $Y\sim U(0,1)$ and $$f(X,Y) =x+y - \lfloor x+y \rfloor$$ That is, $f(x,y)$ is the remainder of the sum $x+y$.

Comment: So we need to have some function $f(X,Y)$ that is invariant for the value of $X$ such that $f(a,Y) \sim f(b,Y) $ for every $a,b$. We can have this when there are symmetries. E.g. the mirroring in the case when $f(-1,Y)$ and $f(1,Y)$ have the same distribution. And in that last example we had that a shift of $X$ results in the same distribution because of a modular arithmetic.